# How to model this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, biology

I'm having some problems on how to model this situation correctly, using difference equations.

Say there's a medicine that has a half-life of 12 hours (every 12 hours, the amount of it on your blood is multiplied by 1/2) and 1g of this medicine is injected every 8 hours, also starting with 1g at $t=0$.
Given this situation, I'm asked:

a) What will be the amount of medicine on a patient's blood after one day?

b) After 5 days?

My proposed model is:
$y_{t}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2/3}y_{t-1} + 1$, where $t$ jumps in eight hours steps. I can solve this recurrence equation but the answer I get is different from the answers my problem set gives me. I think I should solve and than evaluate it at $t=3$ for one day and $t=15$ for 5 days. Is my model wrong? Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without telling us (briefly) how you solved the recurrence, what is your answer, and what is the given answer, how would we be able to pinpoint the problem? The recurrence itself looks correct.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for that. The general solution, with $y_{0}=1$ would be: $y_{t} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2t/3} + \left(\frac{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2t/3}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2/3}} \right)$. My solution for $t=3$, for instance, is about 2,27g and the given answer is 1,52. Any idea on how to solve that? Thanks a lot and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your model, nor with your general formula. Your answer for $t=3$ is also correct for after one day just after the 4th injection. (If it is just before the 4th injection then of course it would be $1$ gram less.)

Comment: Thanks for the support. Even with 1g less, it would also be different from the given answer. I will have to ask that to the instructor. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @RaulGuarini: Yes I cannot figure out why the given answer is 1.52g.